# Is there a way to check if child list has changed without downloading it in Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of items which store their names and other data within them. All my other working lists use IDs of these items. So in order for UI to display item names to user instead of IDs, app must pre-download whole list of items and substitute ID with item names. I'd like to cache this list locally and only download it again in case it has changed. For know I only thought of having a version number of the list and tracking changes using it. But maybe there is another way to check if children of the node have changed without downloading them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'll increment item list version number in each of administrator's functions that are used to edit the list and in user's app I'll check this version number to see if user needs to renew local copy of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Try Calling addChildEventListener instead of addListenerForSingleValueEvent.

read this for understanding all overwrite method. https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/ChildEventListener.html

Comment: To my understanding, when I add ChildEventListener, for the first time it triggers onChildAdded() for each child available, that is it reads all the data which I want to avoid in the first place, because this data will be changed very rarely.

Comment: I think I'll add function to increment list version number to each of administrators functions that are used to edit the list and in user app I'll check for this version number to see if I need to renew the list.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [addChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data) and for save data at cache you have to call `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` [Disk Persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities)

Comment: To my understanding this is a solution for network glitches. But if the network connection is OK, I think that ChildEventListener will launch onChildAdded() for each child available and read the data which I want to prevent in the first place, if local copy received from previous application launch is newest.